# How to allow Drag&Drop of files from Android file system to WPF/c# application?

Tags: c#, android, wpf, windows, drag-and-drop

I have a Windows Desktop WPF/C# application and I want to allow the user to select video files from their DCIM folder on their smartphone into the application. The user will open the DCIM folder in Windows Explorer, select a few files and drag them into my application. There I want to be able to access the list of file names and then copy them to a local temporary folder.

I have drag/drop working fine for files selected from a local folder, but when the files are coming from a smartphone, I am unable to access the dropped file list.

This call returns false when the files are selected from a phone folder (when called in Window_Drop)

```
e.Data.ContainsFileDropList()
```

What am I doing wrong?

--Edit--

I've been able to use the code below to access a partial path:

```
                object s = e.Data.GetData("FileGroupDescriptorW");

                Stream theStream = (Stream)e.Data.GetData("FileGroupDescriptorW");
                byte[] fileGroupDescriptor = new byte[512];
                theStream.Read(fileGroupDescriptor, 0, 512);

                StringBuilder fileName = new StringBuilder("");

                for (int i = 0; i < fileGroupDescriptor.Length; i++)
                { 
                    if(fileGroupDescriptor[i] != 0)
                    fileName.Append(Convert.ToChar(fileGroupDescriptor[i])); 
                }

                string theFile = fileName.ToString();
```

The output is this:

```
d@_ZèØÕÁVID-20200201-WA0002.mp4
```

Which is ... almost... a path? 'VID-20200201-WA0002.mp4' is the filename of the drag/dropped file. But what is the first part? Can I use this to copy the selected file to a temporary folder on my windows machine?